# Dividing a DataArray and putting names to each Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a data array with dimensions 1 x 95125. I want to extract data from it and then give each a name. For example

```
Station00001=[R{:,1:13}]

Station00002=[R{:,15:27}]
.....

Station06518
```

The question is, is it possible to create a vector with all the wanted names and then open each data from the data array as above but with all the files with a for loop to its corresponding file
This is what I did but its not working

```
for i= 1:(length(R)/14)
    k=0:((length(R)/14)-1)
    A(i)=1+14.*k;
    B(i)=A+12;

    Stations (i)= [R{:,A(i):B(i)}];

end
```

Comment: take a look at tables in matlab

Comment: You could look at [struct](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html?nocookie=true).This is a similar question and answer [Having a variable name dependant on the imported file name](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27216641/2545927)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is fine; not sure why you would want to store the A and B indices in an array, though.

```
numStations = floor(length(R)/14); %# careful: the number of columns in R is not a multiple of 14
Stations = cell(1,numStations); 
for i= 1:numStations

    fromColumn = (i-1)*14+1;
    toColumn   = i*14-1;

    Stations{i}= [R{:,fromColumn:toColumn}];

end
```

To access the data from Station 25, use `Stations{25}`